# How to use the Slack API to subscribe to a thread?

Tags: slack-api

I'm playing with the Slack API and my goal is to replicate the "Follow Message" functionality provided in the slack web/desktop/mobile clients as shown in the screenshot below. I haven't found the right end point or permissions to make this work. Looking at the web client network calls I see a request to https://slack.com/api/subscriptions.thread.add? however, that only seems to work with xoxc tokens from what I can tell, and those are not officially supported tokens. Moreover, that end point isn't listed in the documentation.

When I try that endpoint with my xoxp token, with all OAuth permissions I could add, results in:

```
"ok": false,
"error": "not_allowed_token_type",
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve my goal of programmatically following a message? I'm sure I could post a message in the thread to achieve the same goal, but that is really messy and clutters the thread with noise.

Thanks!

[image: Slack Follow Message]